# How to Implement waving(Like pendulam) ropes effect in COCOS2D?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, game-engine, box2d-iphone

I am trying to implement wave effect when any thing hits the hanging object, how can I achieve the both,:

1.Hang an object in air(as it will be a dynamic body which will wave)

2.implement waving effect on that body

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer isn't in cocos2d but in your physics engine, if you are using box2d check the [distance joint](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082974). not sure on chipmunk.

Answer (score 0):

in testbed example see the chain example.

u can create no of small boxes and joint them looks like rope.

but be careful while specify the anchorpoint.